# Camel get string from file

Tags: java, string, apache-camel

I'm trying to get string from xml file and set its value to an object, but can't figure out how to do this. Here's what I've done so far:

```
public class Converter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
    xmlJsonFormat.setTypeHints(String.valueOf("YES"));

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverter(User.class, String.class, new UserConverter());        

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("ftp://Mike@localhost")
                    .to("seda:input").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("seda:out");
        }
    });

    User user = context.getTypeConverter().convertTo(User.class, "seda:out"); // Here i need to access string from "seda:out"

    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println(user.getLogin());

}

private static class UserConverter extends TypeConverterSupport {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(String.valueOf(value.toString()));
        return (T) user;
    }
}
}
```

My output is **seda:out**, but i need the output to be the string, that is in `seda:out`.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a TypeConvertor, use a processor. A processor shall extract the string from camel exchange and create the user object. Your route should be something as follows

```
from("ftp://Mike@localhost").to("file://someDirPath").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).process(
    new Processor() {
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
          // create the User object and set in  the body
          exchange.getIn().setBody(userObject);} });
```

Comment: What should i put as parameter into `process()` method? The way you've written it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please explain what `exchange.getIn().setBody(userObject)` does? In my situation code works the same way with and without this line.

Comment: In the process method you get the String unmarshalled from the Ftp'ed file and then use that to create the User object. In order to access it in the next step of route; it has been set on the exchange. So again you can need to call exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class) for retrieval. Exchange object in your case shall act as a context that you can use to get/set the User object.